# Can anyone please tell me how I'm able to produce divs in the same row even though they are block elements?

Tags: html, css, position

I was asked to produce my divs in a horizontal fashion (blue yellow red). However I've realized that I was able to do so without changing the display property. Can anyone pls tell me how's that possible?
Here's my html code

```
<div class="red">
</div>

<div class="blue">
</div>

<div class="yellow">
</div>
```

Here's my CSS code

```
.red
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:red; 
    position:relative;
    left:200px;

}
.blue
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue; 
    position:relative;
    bottom:100px;

}
.yellow
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:yellow; 
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
    bottom:200px;

}
```

[image: This is the output]

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: kindly check my answer present down below

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is adding a parent div and using flex-box to get them inline using `flex-direction: row` (wich is default so you won't have to set it by default to get a row of elements)

```css
.red
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:red; 
    position:relative;
    left:200px;

}
.blue
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue; 
    position:relative;

}
.yellow
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:yellow; 
    position:relative;
    left:100px;

}
.flex-parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
<div class="red">
</div>

<div class="blue">
</div>

<div class="yellow">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is not about how to achieve, OP needs explanation on the current behavior.

Comment: OP asked how its possible, well like this it is

Answer (score 0):

Change order of  for achieving [ (1) blue (2) yellow (3)red ] result

You can simply add `float` property which will get you the desired result without any change in `display` properties or you can even use `display: inline-block;` for the desired results...

with **display: inline-block;**

```css
.red
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:red; 
    display: inline-block;

}
.blue
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue; 
    display: inline-block;

}
.yellow
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:yellow; 
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
</div>

<div class="yellow">
</div>

<div class="red">
</div>
```

with **float: left;**

```css
.red
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:red; 
    float: left;
}
.blue
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue; 
    float: left;
}
.yellow
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:yellow; 
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
</div>

<div class="yellow">
</div>

<div class="red">
</div>
```

with **position: absolute;**

```css
.red
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:red; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}
.blue
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue; 
    position: absolute;
}
.yellow
{
    height:100px; 
    width:100px;
    background-color:yellow; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
</div>

<div class="yellow">
</div>

<div class="red">
</div>
```

Have a nice day!!!
regards,
Om Chaudhary

Comment: If you think that I was able to answer your query then kindly accept my answer... thats's all!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about behavior of the code you added with the question then Basically what you have done is used the css `position` property to achieve the goal. There are 5 types of `positions` in css which are

`static`
`relative`
`absolute`
`fixed`
`sticky`

and if you set anyone of these properties to an html element then you can control its position using left, right, top and bottom coordinates.

You can study more about these [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

But its not best practice to use these to position elements unless it is required by flow and can't be achieved by other methods, like in your code you can easily achieve the result using css Flexbox, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) is a great resource to study flexbox.

Hope it clears your query.